# ReferenceError: LocalDateTime not defined

Tags: javascript, js-joda

I am trying to use the js joda in my HTML page and following is the code extract:

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-joda/1.6.2/js-joda.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <button type="button" onclick="timeZoneFunction()">Show Time Zone</button>
      <script>
        function timeZoneFunction(){
          var dt = new LocalDateTime();
          var zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
        }
      </script>
     </body>
   </html>
```

For some reason I keep getting the error that the LocalDateTime or the ZonedDateTime is not defined. I tried placing the local javascript in the head section but no luck. Cannot think of where I am going wrong. Pointers please...

Answer (score 0):

Used the namespace JSJoda before the function calls and it appears to work...